# how to speed up expanding list from map iterator

Tags: python, pandas

I have some text data in a pandas column. Basically each document is part of the column value. Each document is multi sentence long.

I wanted to split each document into sentence and then for each sentence I want to get a list of words. So if a document is 5 sentence long, I will have a list of list of words with length 5.

I used a mapper function to do some operations on that and got a list of words for each sentence of a text. Here is a mapper code:

```
def text_to_words(x):
    """ This function converts sentences in a text to a list of words

    """
    nlp=spacy.load('en')
    txt_to_words= [str(doc).replace(".","").split(" ") for doc in nlp(x).sents]
    return txt_to_words
```

Then I did this:

```
%%time
txt_to_words=map(text_to_words,pandas_df.log_text_cleaned)
```

It got done in 70 micro seconds and I got a mapper iterator.

Now if I want to add each list of list of words of each document as a new value of a new column in the same pandas data frame.

I can simply do this:

```
txt_to_words=[*map(text_to_words,pandas_df.log_text_cleaned)]
```

Which will expand the map iterator and store it in txt_to_words as list of list of words.

But this process is very slow.

I even tried looping over the map object :

```
txt_to_words=map(text_to_words,pandas_df.log_text_cleaned)


txt_to_words_list=[]
for sent in txt_to_words: 
    txt_to_words_list.append(sent)
```

But this is similar slow.

extracting the output from a mapper object is very slow. And I just have 67K documents in that pandas data frame column.

Is there a way this can be sped up?

Thanks

Comment: "It got done in 70 micro seconds and I got a mapper iterator" - the work *did not* get done. That's the point of `map` returning an iterator: it doesn't do the work until you loop over it. You didn't make the work faster. You just told Python to procrastinate.

Comment: It's unlikely that the list-building is actually the slow part here. When you construct a `map`, that's fast because it doesn't really do much but set up the lazy iterator for you to consume later. When you convert that to a list, it has to evaluate every element of the iterator, doing all the lazy work you postponed until later, and that's where your time goes.

Comment: That being said: calling `list(…)` instead of `[*…]` or a `for` statement will be significantly faster… it's just that it'll be speeding up the part that doesn't matter, shaving off microseconds of your overall process.

Comment: even using list() is painstakingly slow. There is hardly much difference in that and using * or for loop. Any other suggestions which can speed up this? Is there a way I can send each sentence one one line to a txt file so that all sentences of all documents simply get written to a txt file on disk one below the other? I tried doing that but it erases all previous sentences and only keeps the last documents sentences. The file is not created yet so it has to be in 'w' mode for it to write the first document there.

Comment: @Baktaawar Yes. As I just explained to you, that's because you're optimizing the wrong thing. The list construction takes microseconds, the actual work takes seconds. So speeding up the list construction part of that will have no visible impact.

Comment: If you don't believe me, try constructing a `collections.deque(map…, maxlen=0)`. This is the fastest way to consume an iterator—it doesn't have to allocate any memory or store anything. And you'll see that it still makes no visible difference.

Comment: right I got that. So basically this won't help in anyway in memory. Can I somehow push it to disk on a txt file one below the other?

Comment: Accessing the disk is not going to make things faster.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's in `pandas_df.log_text_cleaned`, or what `nlp(x).sents` returns, but those are the kinds of things you need to be looking at. See my answer for some help getting started.

Comment: @abarnert: Actually, `[*...]` has exactly the same per-item cost as `list(...)`, and a slightly lower fixed cost. Both of them do all the real work at the C layer on CPython, and the syntax based version has special bytecode support that avoids the general call dispatch overhead of `list(...)` (saves a whopping 100-150 ns to do `[*...]`). That said, everything else you said is correct. If each item takes 10 *ms* to produce, it doesn't matter if you save 10-50 *ns* off the per-item cost to add it to the `list`. `(*...,)` is slower than `tuple(...)` though (makes `list`, then copies to `tuple`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger It has a higher fixed cost in a quick `%timeit` test with 3.6 on Linux and 3.7alpha on Mac—137us vs. 129us (vs. 106us for `deque(maxlen=0)`, although that difference gets wider for much larger iterators, and the other one doesn't). Maybe it would be different with lots of tiny lists (where the cost of looking up a global and calling a function actually matters) instead of a smaller number of decent-sized ones.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is that the fastest way to convert an iterator to a list is probably by calling `list` on it, although that may depend on the size of your lists.

**However, this is not going to matter, except to an unnoticeable, barely-measurable degree.**

The difference between `list(m)`, `[*m]`, or even an explicit `for` statement is a matter of microseconds at most, but your code is taking seconds. In fact, you could even eliminate almost all the work done by `list` by using `collections.deque(m, maxlen=0)` (which just throws away all of the values without allocating anything or storing them), and you *still* won't see a difference.

---

Your real problem is that the work done for each element is slow.

Calling `map` doesn't actually do that work. All it does is construct a lazy iterator that sets up the work to be done later. When is later? When you convert the iterator to a list (or consume it in some other way).

So, it's that `text_to_words` function that you need to speed up.

And there's at least one obvious candidate for how to do that:

```
def text_to_words(x):
    """ This function converts sentences in a text to a list of words

    """
    nlp=spacy.load('en')
    txt_to_words= [str(doc).replace(".","").split(" ") for doc in nlp(x).sents]
    return txt_to_words
```

You're loading in an entire English tokenizer/dictionary/etc. for each sentence? Sure, you'll get some benefit from caching after the first time, but I'll bet it's still way too slow to do for every sentence.

If you were trying to speed things up by making it a local variable rather than a global (which probably won't matter, but it might), that's not the way to do it; this is:

```
nlp=spacy.load('en')

def text_to_words(x, *. _nlp=nlp):
    """ This function converts sentences in a text to a list of words

    """
    txt_to_words= [str(doc).replace(".","").split(" ") for doc in _nlp(x).sents]
    return txt_to_words
```

Comment: Well I don't have that nlp load in my actual function. Its outside. I added it here for understanding what nlp variable is. So the above doesn't help as I already have that outside.